# Windows 7 "Not Responding"

Tags: windows-7, browser, freeze

At my office we've got 2 Dell XPS M1530 laptops. Both have been running up to date installations of Windows 7 with NOD 32 Anti Virus for months now with no problems. Last week however both started freezing with "Not responding" issues every few minutes when browsing the web. It doesn't matter which browser, the latest versions of Firefox, Chrome and IE8 all do the same. After a few minutes the browser "wakes up again" but freezes again very soon.

I suspect it's an OS update issue, a driver/OS conflict or something. Anybody got a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it. After disabling Microsoft Security Essentials the responsiveness of my laptop was immediately back to normal, and actually much better than it's been in months (All the months I've had MS Security Essential installed), especially when browsing the web.

Comment: Do you mean you were running two AV tools (NOD and MSE)?

Comment: Indeed. I wasn't aware that MSE was a full on AV. Installed it at work on orders from "above" thinking it's only an anti spyware tool. Obviously not a good idea to run 2 AV's.

Answer (score 0):

If it isn't a network issue, then I would look at disabling any firewall/internet-filtering functionality of NOD.